# How to cache wordpress get_posts query using transients?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, transient

I have a website with over 100,000 posts. On a term taxonomy page, the main query `WP_Query->get_posts()` is the slowest. I want to cache the results of this query using `transients-api`. I tried hooking into `pre_get_posts` using the following code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts',function($query){
  
  if ( !$query->is_main_query() ) return $query;
  
  $key = md5( serialize( $query ) );
  
  $transient = get_transient($key);
  
  if ( $transient ) return $transient;

  
 $query_result = new WP_Query( $query );

set_transient($key,$query_result,HOUR_IN_SECONDS);

return  $query_result;
  
    });
```

The above code is not working. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) is used to modify the query arguments before the query is run. The `$query` is passed in by reference, so any changes you make in your function will be reflected in the query that's actually run. The `return` that you're doing will be ignored.

I think you might be making your problem *worse* here: you're running the query, putting the results into a transient with an hour's lifetime, then `return`ing a value that will not be used. Then the query runs *again* once your action is done.

Comment: Thanks. How to achieve `transient-api` caching for such queries then?

Comment: It seems the primary advice given is "Install a caching plugin": [Optimization—Caching](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/optimization-caching/).

Comment: Caching is already enabled on the website. As per the question, I need a way to cache db query results.

Comment: Looking at the core code used to fetch posts, it appears WordPress already does a lot of caching when it's grabbing posts, using its built-in object cache. (I seem to recall that the object cache uses transients or—if it's available—a service like Redis, but I can't find the reference.) Are you using core functions like `get_posts()` or is there a custom function to gather the relevant posts? If the latter, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/416031/edit) to show us what you're trying.

Comment: The WordPress core function `get_posts()` that runs on taxonomy page as per default wordpress code to fetch posts in that taxonomy is a bit slow when taxonomy has a lot of posts assigned to it.